# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Tengo un código para que desde un input `select`, al seleccionar una opción traiga desde la BD ciertos datos con XMLHttpRequest, sin embargo me esta arrojando el siguiente error justo cuando selecciono una opción del `select`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fragmento de código de JS es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrarDatosPsicologo(str){
        if (str==""){
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML= "";
            return;
        }
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
            }
        }
        
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "../procesos/sesiones/obtenerDatosPsicologo.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    //setInterval(function(){mostrarDatosPsicologo();}, 1000);
</script>
```

El fragmento de código del elemento HTML es:

```
<div class="row justfy-content-center">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                                    <hr>
                                    <label for="psicologo_asignado">Datos del Psicologo asignado</label>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="txtHint"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
```

Esto último dentro de un `FORM` con `method="POST"`, no se si ese sea el error solo que no puedo sacarlo del `FORM`.

De igual manera comparto el archivo `obtenerDatosPsicologo.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/datatable/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $q=intval($_GET['q']);
    include "../../clases/Conexion.php";
    $con = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $con->conectar();

    if(!$conexion){
        die('No se pudo conectar al servidor: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
    $sql1= "SELECT 
                id_usuario,
                primer_nombre,
                segundo_nombre,
                apellido_paterno,
                apellido_materno
            FROM
                usuarios
            WHERE
                id = '".$q"'";
    $respuesta1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql1);

        echo "<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Primer Nombre</th>
                    <th>Segundo Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                    <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                </tr>";
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta1)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['primer_nombre'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['segundo_nombre'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['apellido_paterno'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['apellido_materno'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }

echo "</table>";

?>

<script src="../public/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

La base de datos si tiene los datos y celdas correctamente ya lo verifiqué, también intente mandar mas `echo` con algunas validaciones dentro del archivo PHP sin embargo el resultado era el mismo.

El `setInterval` lo puse para hacer una prueba y el error se actualizaba cada segundo, como especifique en el código, solo que no tengo idea si es un error desde JS o cometí algún error en el PHP y no envía los datos correctamente.
Los códigos de JS y PHP los obtuve de W3Schools, seguí las indicaciones que daban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método document.getElementById("txtHint") busca un elemento con id="txtHint" y tienes un div con class="txtHint", una solución es cambiar class="txtHint" por id="txtHint".